# Correlation of variable to squared variable

Tags: correlation, regression-coefficients, multicollinearity

If I have a certain variable, let's say Age. Then why if I square this variable, is the correlation between $age$ and $age^2$ not equal to 1. e.g. I get a correlation coefficient of 0.983. is this something structural or does it depend on my data somehow?
Thanks!

Comment: It is data dependent. Try it with age = (-1, 0, 1).

Answer (score 1):

This is because for a perfect correlation you need a linear relationship between your two variables i.e. if we see an increase in $X$ of size $a$ we will see exactly an increase in $Y$ of size $b$.

By squaring the variable you no longer have a linear relationship but a quadratic one. The effect is very clear to see when you start going into higher powers.

Code and graph for square relationship overlaid with linear regression line:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data_frame(
    age = runif( 100 , 20 , 80),
    age2 = age^2
)
ggplot( dat , aes(x = age , y = age2)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth( method = "lm" , se  = F)
```

[image]

Code and graph for age ^ 6

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data_frame(
    age = runif( 100 , 20 , 80),
    age6 = age^6
)
ggplot( dat , aes(x = age , y = age6)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth( method = "lm" , se  = F)
```

[image]

EDIT: This is true of Pearson correlation. If you use other methods such as Spearman correlation that relies on the ranking of data then you will still get a perfect correlation of 1 even after the square transformation as the ranks have been preserved.

Comment: As in my comment on the other answer to date, the special case in which $x$ is binary and also  $0$ or $1$ is an exception, as then the correlation is $1$. (Occasionally I have met people wondering about adding a squared indicator (dummy) predictor as well as the original, the motive being to improve the fit.)

Answer (score 1):

The correlation will depend on the distribution. For instance, see [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/336334/36041) to a similar question that shows that for symmetrical distributions the correlation will be zero.

It's very easy to see how, look at the picture below. The line $y=x$ and curve $y=x^2$: on positive x they go together, and on negative x they go in opposite directions. So, if you have a symmetric distribution such as Gaussian on $x\in\mathbb R$, entire real line, then the correlation will be precisely zero.
However, if you only look at the positive side, i.e. $x>0$, then the correlation will be very high on almost any distribution.

[image]

So, it's not just the functional form, it's also the underlying distribution of your data

Comment: On the other hand, a symmetric distribution for $x$ with half $0$ and half $1$ will yield a correlation of $1$ as in that case $x$ and $x^2$ are identical. So that is one counter-example to your first generalisation. In fact your first paragraph appears to assume mean zero.